# How to use Spine.js with millions of records and a filter?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, spine.js

I'm making a webapp where the user is presented with a list. There are millions of records in total, but the user can only see a hundred at a time. More records should only be loaded when the user reaches the bottom of the list. (Scrolls down the page.) The user also has some filters to find the record in the list he/she is looking for.

So, I suppose LocalStorage wouldn't be a good idea because of the massive amounts of records. But how can I get Spine.js to work with this use case? A similar use case could be an online email client with thousands of emails.

Fetching all the records from the server isn't a good idea, so I suppose a way of updating the records with AJAX on the fly would be the best option? How can this be done with Spine.js, or do I have to write my own library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "Pagination" section in the Spine docs: http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax

Comment: Since the user can filter on the records, I suppose the best way of doing this is to filter locally, and then query the server to recieve all the records that match the filter? So the user gets to see some records before the rest from the server pops up. If one record is fetched twice, will it become a duplicate, or just update the original?

Comment: The reason why I'm asking how "the correct" way of doing things is, is because this is a framework designed to be used in a special way, with a particular mindset. It's not me who created Spine.js, after all..

Comment: a record fetched twice will not be duplicated if it has the same id. the second time it is is fetched it will overwrite the current existing client record